# Sharepoint survey- drive questions from answers to earlier rating question

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey, conditional

I have a survey of a product portfolio. The first question is the rating question covering all products in the portfolio. I then want subsequent question section for each of the product that had a rating other than N/A. Is this possible with the SharePoint survey app w/o (significant) coding/ using the branching logic

TIA

[image: SharePoint Survey Rating Question]

Answer (score 0):

In a created question, you could add branching logic in the question settings.

Settings -> Survey settings -> Select the question -> Branching Logic.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't follow your suggestion. Is there a way to branch based on all "Products" that got a value other than N/A? Won't the possible choices in the screenshot shown above be the values the user selected for each product?